# Unable to boot Windows 10 after Ubuntu 14 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

After a very long and difficult Windows 10/Ubuntu 14 dual boot installation (the usual Nvidia/Nouveau compatibility issues), I finally have Ubuntu working, only to discover that Windows had disappeared from the (finally functional) grub menu.

`sudo update-grub` couldn't find Windows. I added it as an entry in 40_custom and tried to boot it, only to get an error message that says: "the boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors"

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc000000a  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

So far I have tried:
 boot-repair MBR: completed without errors, did not fix problem
 bootrec: as above
 windows reset: The drive is locked
 [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix): file not found

I don't have anything actually installed on windows yet, so it's not a big deal to reinstall, but I don't want that to damage the Ubuntu install, because that took a really long time to get working. Is there anything I haven't tried yet that might work?

[Here are the results from the boot-info script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLcjDYV9IgrNzBaOHc4ZzdURW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Okat, it turns out what happened was I had installed windows in BIOS mode and ubuntu in UEFI mode, and boot repair had automatically converted windows from MBR to GPT and the windows boot manager didn't like that. 
What I ended up doing was creating a backup of ubuntu with rsync and formatted the whole drive, then reinstalled the both in UEFI and restored ubuntu from the backup.